# Consultar y actualizar varios datos foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

estoy realizando un pequeño sistema de inventario,
Se registra una compra en una tabla y cuando se cierra dicha compra se actualiza el estatus de esas compra a "Cerrado" Y debe descontar el producto de la tabla de inventario.

Tengo el codigo para actualizar cada ID por medio de array.
Lo que no logro hacer es como consultar el inventario de cada producto, descontar y actualizar el producto comprado.

Agradezco su ayuda

```
$COD_PRO= array(); //OBTENEGO LOS DATOS DE FORMULARIO Y LOS GUARDO EN ARRAY
$STOCK_UP= array();

foreach($COD_PRO as $key=>$value)
    $COD_PRO[]= $value;

foreach($STOCK_UP as $key=>$value)
    $STOCK_UP[]= $value;
    // RECORRO EL ARRAY Y OBTENGO EL CODIGO DE PRODUCTO
            for($i=0; $i<count($COD_PRO); $i++)
            {            
             //ACTUALIZO DE ACUERDO AL VALOR DEL STOCK ACTUAL
              $_UPDATE_SQL="UPDATE $PV_INVET SET STOCK_ACTUAL='$STOCK_UP[$i]' WHERE CODIGO='$COD_PRO[$i]'"; 
            mysqli_query($conexion,$_UPDATE_SQL); 

            }
echo("
        <script>
            alert('Categorías actualizadas exitosamente.');
            window.location.href='inventario.php';
        </script>
        "); `
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir comentarios al código explicando lo que pretendes hacer? No acabo de entender de dónde sacas los datos y para qué añades a `$COD_PRO` y `$STOCK_UP` su propio contenido... ¿qué es `$nombre_categoria`? ¿Por qué no actualizas el inventario desde la propia base de datos?

Comment: Ya comente lo que hace ese fragmento de codigo, pero tienes alguna idea de como puedo consultar y a su vez actualizar la información?
Lo que pretendo es consultar el inventario del item X , saber el stock actual y descontarlo de acuerdo al array STOCK_UP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ya sabes cuánto ha variado el stock, no es necesario que hagas una consulta para obtener el valor inicial. Puedes hacer un `UPDATE` directamente con esa variación:

```
UPDATE PV_INVET
  SET STOCK_ACTUAL=STOCK_ACTUAL-14
  WHERE CODIGO=1;
```

He supuesto este dataset para comprobar el funcionamiento con un ejemplo mínimo:

```
CREATE TABLE PV_INVET(
  STOCK_ACTUAL float,
  CODIGO int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  );
INSERT INTO PV_INVET (STOCK_ACTUAL)
  VALUES (18);
```

Como cabe esperar, el stock del artículo 1 pasa de 18 a 14 unidades. Pues entiendo que son unidades consumidas, no repuestas.

Espero que te resulte de ayuda. El `foreach` y el resto de cuestiones ya veo que las tienes controladas. Si tienes cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola, me funciono en mysql, solo que al aplicarlo en mi codigo no lo aplica, que podria estar erroneo? STOCK_ACTUAL=STOCK_ACTUAL-$CANTIDAD[$i]' WHERE CODIGO='$CODIGO[$i]'";

Comment: ¿Tal vez las comillas?

Comment: Ya quedo resuelto, resulta que la variable que llama a la DB, estaba incorrecta. 
Sobre tu ejemplo de actualizar me funciono a la perfección.
Gracias.